# Postgres, add new lines for each missing days

Tags: postgresql, date, row, line, addition

Forgive what may be a silly question, but I'm not much of a database guru.

**I have this table :**

id_data (serial)  | udate (date)

```
1               | 1984-02-10   
2               | 1984-02-12
3               | 1984-02-15
```

And **i would like to add new lines for each missing days** ***until today***
, like this one :

id_data (serial)    | udate (date)

```
*               | 1984-02-10   
*               | 1984-02-11
*               | 1984-02-12
*               | 1984-02-13
*               | 1984-02-14
*               | 1984-02-15
...             | 2013-12-17 (today)
```

Is it possible ?
Thanks in advance!

~~ ~~ ~~ ~~ ~~ ~~ ~~ ~~ ~~ ~~ ~~ ~~ ~~ ~~ ~~ ~~ ~~ ~~ ~~ ~~ ~~ ~~ ~~ ~~ ~~ ~~ ~~ ~~ ~~ ~~ ~~ ~~

Nb : the table 2 shows a select * from table order by udate

Edit : this is a really small exemple because i can't post a full example between 1984 to 2013 **for each missin days until today**. The main goal is to show illustrate what i need in the table bellow.

Comment: Yes,but your example shows duplicate ID data which you say is serial, so it wouldn't be allowed-- I can write a query to generate new dates, and NEW (appended) ID's but not with duplicate ID's. When I look at the ID column on your expected results, I can't determine what logic you're using to generate those.

Comment: Actually i search a query for any date, not only this one.
I will add this in my topic to make it more accurate :)

Comment: your query with new date could be quite good, don't mind with ids i just need a query wih new lines for missing days in my table

Comment: I edit my answer to make her more accurate, the new one is :
"And i would like to add new lines for each missing days until today"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generate the empty lines using `generate_series()`:

```
select d::date
from generate_series(timestamp '1984-02-10',
                     timestamp '1984-02-15',
                     interval '1 day') d;
```

For the id generation, create a [temporary] sequence if you don't want to use the one from your table:

```
create temporary sequence tmp_id_data_seq start with 4;
```

You can then generate new ids like:

```
select nextval('tmp_id_data_seq');
```

Then outer join the two:

```
select coalesce(data.id_data, nextval('tmp_id_data_seq')) as id_data,
       d::date as udate
from generate_series(timestamp '1984-02-10',
                     timestamp '1984-02-15',
                     interval '1 day') dates (d)
left join data on data.udate = dates.d::date;
```

Naturally, you'd want to adjust the two bounds and the start value as needed in the above.

Comment: Thank you Denis for you answer. Generate_serie seems to be a good item !
I have a problem with you 4th query, the number 4 with select coalesce ... doesn't work (error : id_data doesn't exist)

Comment: You named the sequence `tmp_id_data_seq3`?

Comment: Does select nextval('tmp_id_data_seq3') return anything?

Comment: Yes, select nextval('tmp_id_data_seq'); return 13 (then 14,15 etc)

Comment: So that's good. Try it with `data.id_data` like in my edit. The field is the field name you posted, so adjust the column name accordingly if that's not what you actually have. Btw, you can restart the sequence like `select setval('tmp_id_data_seq', 3);` if needed. And frankly, methinks you should just keep the field null and worry about setting an id in a more appropriate location later on.

Comment: I have a error which says something missing for FROM in select coalesce ... etc

Comment: If you can do `select id_data, udate from data`, you should be able to run it… :-|

Comment: Seems i'm little bit tired ^^ : i try it on a new sql window and it works perfectly ! Thank you very much Denis you are great :-)